# Eclipse Remote debugging with Linux through CYGWIN isn't working

Tags: eclipse, debugging, cygwin, weblogic

I use Windows xp with cygwin to run web-logic server that is located in my machine.
So I have the whole setup in one machine.

But I couldn't make the remote debugger to work with Eclipse.

Here is the debug command in startWSL.sh
export DEBUG_OPTS = -Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=1044,server=y,suspend=y

But I couldn't debug from Eclipse, the connection times out.

Do I miss something that I need to do when using CYGWIN?
Help appreciated!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DEBUG_OPTS is not a recognized env variable in startWebLogic.sh standard script. You may want to use JAVA_OPTIONS variable instead.